# Countability of set of binary strings of finite length

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So I was thinking about the countability of the set of binary strings of finite length.
I approached using two ways.
The worst thing is I am getting different answers in both approaches.
Here is the way I proceeded.

My Ideas.
If I am given a binary string whose left most digit is $0$ then truncate it. Remove the $0$. Do it untill you get a $1$ at the left most place.
This is simply an extension of the fact that $0334$ and $334$ are equal and the $0$ in the left of $3$ in $0334$ isn't necessary!

Now coming to the solution
Method 1.
Map each binary string to it corresponding decimal representation.
And map each Natural Number to the binary representation.
This is a bijection as both the mapping are $1-1$.

Hence our set is countable as its isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

Method 2.
Consider the mapping from the set of Binary Strings to Power Set of $\mathbb{N}$.
If the binary string is $a_k a_{k-1} ...a_3 a_2 a_1$ then define the set $$X=\{k\in \mathbb{N} | a_k=1\}$$
This also gives a bijection which shows that the set of binary string is Uncountable!

Where is the Error?

Comment: It's worth noting that your mapping in 'method 1' _also_ isn't a bijection; `0001` and `1` are _different_ binary strings, but they map to the same value.

Comment: Also, $0334$ isn't a binary string.

Comment: @CameronBuie I never said that it is! I had given an example that adding 0 at the left most place isn't necessary as we do in $decimal$(That's why I considered 0334)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Did you read the complete post? Can you re-read again, the second paragraph atleast?

Comment: @SunShine I did, I assure you. You say 'remove the zero; do it until you get a 1 at the left most place. This is an extension of the fact that `0110` and `110` (I'm replacing your example with binary) are equal and the 0 isn't necessary!'  The point is that the zero may not be necessary when you consider 0110 as a _number_ - but the _string_ `0110` is completely different than the string `110`. When constructing a bijection, you're not allowed to arbitrarily throw out parts of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping in "method 2" maps (finite) binary strings to finite subsets of $\mathbb N$. 
The power set of $\mathbb N$ includes infinite subsets.  So this is not a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

The bijection in method 2 is not between $\mathbb N$ and the *finite* binary strings – $\mathbb N$ and its infinite subsets correspond to *infinite* strings, so the set of finite strings cannot be said to be of equal cardinality with $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Answer (score -1):

If the sets $C_1,C_2,...$ are countable (or finite, if one is being picky), then so is $C= \cup_k C_k$. This follows from the same way that one shows that $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable.

In the above case, if $C_k$ is the set of binary strings of length $k$ then we see that
$|C_k| = 2^k$ which is finite. Hence the (countable) union is countable.

Comment: Why the downvote?